# Prisma Typescript Model type issue

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, prisma

I'm currently creating an api with Prisma ORM. And trying to implement it from a Parent dynamically, in order to let all the Childs consume the functions nested in this Parent.

I face an error Type.

There is the code:

```js
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'


export default class Repository {
    
    public model = 'repository';
    private prisma = new PrismaClient();
    

    public async getAll(): Promise<Object> {
      const model = this.model as string;
      const result = await this.prisma[model].findMany();
        return result;
      }

   
}
```

and there is the error on "this.prisma[model].findMany()":

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'Model' can't be used to index type 'PrismaClient<PrismaClientOptions, never, RejectOnNotFound | RejectPerOperation | undefined>'.

Thanks you for the help in advance.

Comment: Can you please add your schema file as well? It would help in understanding your use case better

Comment: The issue is more about the Type. The shema file is working fine if I keep it simple and mention the model name without any variable in order to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to achieve the same. Sadly, because the way Prisma works, this is not currently possible. However, take a look on this.

https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/4397